# SQL server subquery in select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure why this isn't working today, I've done very similar a few times... a simple subquery in my select statement. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT  TradeDate, Symbol, (SELECT COUNT(Symbol) 
     FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol AS T2 WHERE T2.TradeDate = TradeDate 
          AND T2.Symbol = Symbol) AS CountOf 
FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol  WHERE CountOf >1
ORDER BY TradeDate, Symbol
```

tblDailyPricingAndVol is a table with relevant fields TradeDate and Symbol... so there is a record for each symbol, for every trading day (for the most part).. I'd like my query to return the number of duplicates for a trade day, or all trade dates with the count of symbols that have more than one record for that date. Hope that makes sense.. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this..

```
SELECT  TradeDate, Symbol, COUNT(Symbol)  
FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol  
GROUP BY TradeDate, Symbol
HAVING COUNT(Symbol) > 1
ORDER BY TradeDate, Symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use grouping?

```
SELECT  TradeDate, Symbol, COUNT(*) AS CountOf 
FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol  
GROUP BY TradeDate, Symbol
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY TradeDate, Symbol
```

Comment: This is identical to the first answer that was posted.

Comment: Yes when I started to work on this there was no answer, when posted noticed there is already one, but I can't delete it, have to vote to delete ...